# Rust Lifetime Issue with Threads

Tags: rust, thread-safety, lifetime

Here is the code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::thread;

type MAP = HashMap<String, String>;

fn handle_n_times(count: i32, map: &mut MAP) {
    for i in 0..count {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            map.insert(format!("key-{}", i), format!("value-{}", i));
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map: MAP = MAP::new();
    handle_n_times(5, &mut map);
}
```

I cannot compile:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `map`
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
6 | fn handle_n_times(count: i32, map: &mut MAP) {
  |                                    -------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `map`: `&'static mut std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>`
7 |     for i in 0..count {
8 |         thread::spawn(move || {
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

The hint it provides (add a `&'static`) is not helpful.

**Question 1**: How to make this code work?

**Question 2**: After 1 solved, I want to use `std::sync::Arc` to make `map` thread-safe, what's the Rust way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

It is not thread safe to share variables into new threads. In Rust you can not compile this code. You can make the code work via using `Arc<Mutex<Map>>`

Question 2:

You need to change method signature as follows:

```
 handle_n_times(count: i32, arc_map: Arc<Mutex<Map>>)
```

In case you are moving ownership in your `thread::spawn`, you need to clone `Arc` value just before sending it to other thread with

```
 let clone_arc = arc_map.clone();
```

When you want to insert an item to the map you need to get reference from the `Arc<Mutex>` via `lock` and `unwrap`:

```
let map = clone_arc.lock().unwrap();
```

After that you can call `map.insert` with no explicit lifetime requirements.

Here is the full working code as an [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9fe0f7efcfc3a8d30103e56902499b86)